# In-place list modification without for loop in R

Tags: r

I'm wondering whether there is a way to do in-place modification of objects in a list without using a `for` loop. This would be useful, for example, if the individual objects in the list are large and complex, so that we want to avoid making a temporary copy of the entire object. As an example, consider the following code, which creates a list of three data frames, then calculates the vector of maximums across all three data frames for one column of the data, and then assigns that vector to each original data frame. (Code like this is needed when aligning plots in ggplot2.)

```
data_list <- lapply(1:3, function(x) data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10)))

max_x <- do.call(pmax, lapply(data_list, function(d){d$x}))

for( i in 1:length(data_list))
{
  data_list[[i]]$x <- max_x
}
```

Is there any way to write the final part without a `for` loop?

**Answers to some of the questions I'm getting:**

1. What makes me think a copy would be made? I don't know for sure whether a copy would or would not be made. The actual scenario I'm working with deals with entire ggplot graphs (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues/33)). Since they are rather large and complex, it's critical that no copy be made.
2. What's the problem with a `for` loop? I just would rather iterate directly over a list than have to introduce a counter. I don't like counters.
3. Why not use `data.table`? Because I'm actually manipulating ggplot graphs, not data frames. The code provided here is just a simplified example.

Comment: what makes you think a copy is being made of the whole object?

Comment: @MichaelChirico The first assignment inside the loop appears to make a copy: `library(data.table); for( i in 1:length(data_list))
{
  print(address(data_list));
  data_list[[i]]$x <- max_x;
  print(address(data_list))
}`

Comment: @Claus Wilke: What's wrong with using a `for` loop?

Comment: R will copy only the list structure (3 cells) that comprises the data.frame and the modified columns. The unmodified columns do not need to be copied -- they are shared. That is, the `y` and `z` columns will not be copied: `library(data.table); for( i in 1:length(data_list)) { print(address(data_list[i]$y)); data_list[[i]]$x <- max_x; print(address(data_list[i]$y)) }`

Comment: Can you convert the whole thing into a `data.table` and just work with that?

Comment: Something like `rbindlist(data_list, idcol = TRUE)[, ind := sequence(.N), by = .id][, x := max(x), by = ind][]`?

Comment: Without for loop:  `sapply(1:3,function(y){ data_list[[y]]$x<<-max_x })`. It appears no copying is done if I use Roland's method but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide some responses to the questions brought up. The `data.table` approach doesn't work, because I'm interested in the general principle, not the specific case where I'm working with data frames. I just made up the example with data frames to provide a simple, self-contained piece of code.

Comment: As @A.Webb notes, R seems to only allocate a `length(data_list) * length(data_list[[1L]])` "list" structure to share the pointers to your existing "y" and "z" in each "data.frame" and to your "max_x". See the output of `.Internal(inspect(data_list))` before and after your loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base R data structures are copy-on-modify with sharing. Take your example of a data.frame with three numeric columns. Each data.frame is a length 3 "list" vector, each containing a reference to the numeric vectors of the underlying columns. If we modify/replace the first column, R creates a new length 3 data.frame "list" containing references to the new(ly modified) column and the other two unmodified columns.

Let's take a look using the `address` function*

```
set.seed(1)
data_list <- lapply(1:3, function(x) data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10)))

before <- rapply(data_list,address)
```

Now you want to replace the first column with

```
max_x <- do.call(pmax, lapply(data_list, function(d){d$x}))
```

How you do this doesn't much matter, but here's one way without an explicit loop-with-counter

```
data_list <- lapply(data_list,`[<-`,"x",value=max_x)    

after <- rapply(data_list,address)
```

Now compare the addresses before and after. Note that the addresses for the `y` and `z` columns have not changed. Furthermore, all "after" `x` columns have the same address -- the address of `max_x`!

```
address(max_x)
[1] "05660600"

cbind(before,after)

  before     after     
x "0565F530" "05660600"
y "0565F400" "0565F400"
z "05660AC0" "05660AC0"
x "05660A28" "05660600"
y "05660990" "05660990"
z "05660860" "05660860"
x "056607C8" "05660600"
y "05660730" "05660730"
z "05660698" "05660698"
```

This means you don't have to worry as much as you *might* think about making a change to a large data structure. In general, only the modified piece and the skeleton of the data structure will have to be replaced. In this example, the `max_x` vector had to be created anyway, so the only overhead is creating a new 3 cell data.frame "list" and populating it with 3 references**. This, however, could start to become inefficient if you are iteratively "banging on" changes or working with subvectors rather than entire columns. These are use cases for `data.table` that are not applicable to this example.

---

<sub>* The `address` function used here is exported from the `data.table` package.</sub>

<sub>** And, of course, in this example, the 3 cell outer list "list" containing the 3 data.frames themselves.</sub>

Comment: Might be worth noting that the `x` columns only have the same address as `max_x` until they are changed. Then a copy obviously has to happen.

Comment: Until they are changed again? The example is a change *to* `max_x`, so no copy is necessary, just a change of reference to `max_x`. If nothing else points to the old `x` columns, then they will be subject to garbage collection.

Comment: I mean something like: `x <- 1:2; y <- x` If you then do `x[1] <- 3` or `y[1] <- 3` a copy is obviously needed.