# Does adding an element to a list result in copy the list or not?

Tags: r

```
R> x=list()
R> x$a = 1
R> x
$a
[1] 1
```

I am not sure whether in the above code, the old list is copied or is modified in place. Is there a way to test it? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [In-place list modification without for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137503/in-place-list-modification-without-for-loop-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can check the memory location with `tracemem`

```
x=list()
tracemem(x)
#[1] "<0x7f87dec16ec8>"
x$a = 1
tracemem(x)
#[1] "<0x7f87e4f6b4b0>"
```